# ng-pattern for range 1-72 with step 0.5 in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

I need pattern for input (type="text"! not number) when is available numbers from 1 to 72 and available 0.5 (1.5, 2, 2.5, 65.5 ect.)

I tried by

```
ng-pattern="'^(?:[1-9](\.[05]*)?)|(?:[1-6][0-9](\.[05]*)?)|(?:7[01](\.[05]*)?)|72$'"
```

But not work correctly for example "1111a" ect.

Can you help me?
http://regexr.com/3dkks

Comment: Why `input type="text"`?

Comment: a [custom validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) is probably a better option

Comment: Hopeful Llama because I sync value by this plugin
http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo.html and model is not number, but string. I added the same model in this input and in rangeSlider input

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^((?:[1-9](\.[05])?)|(?:[1-6][0-9](\.[05])?)|(?:7[01](\.[05])?)|72)$`

i added the global quotes and remove * after [05]

here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3rGG1aljh41gYcRxCJu?p=preview)